# Set type text inside cell javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, attributes

I want to type text inside the cell but I tried to set attribute with td but it doesn't work. Please help me how can I set attribute to type text in the cell. Thank you for your help!

```js
function addTable() {

    rn = window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1);
    cn = window.prompt("Input number of columns",1);

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");

    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    table.border = '1';
  
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
  
    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(rn, 10); i++) {
      var tr = document.createElement('TR');
      tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  
      for (var j = 0; j < parseInt(cn, 10); j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width = '75';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("text"));
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
  }
addTable();
```

Comment: see my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an `input` element and then append that to `td`:

```js
rn = window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1);
cn = window.prompt("Input number of columns", 1);

var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");

var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.border = '1';

var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);

for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(rn, 10); i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);

  for (var j = 0; j < parseInt(cn, 10); j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('TD');
    td.width = '75';
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('value', 'text');
    td.appendChild(input);
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
}
myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="myDynamicTable">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) attribute: `td.contenteditable = 'true';`.

Depending on how you want to use this value, you might also insert an `input` element.

Comment: Both actually work since it is interpreted as an html attribute.

Comment: that is the weirdest I have ever seen

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps looking for [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)?

```js
function addTable() {

  const rn = +window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1);
  const cn = +window.prompt("Input number of columns", 1);

  const myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");

  const table = document.createElement('table');
  table.border = '1';

  const tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);

  for (let i = 0; i < rn; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    for (let j = 0; j < cn; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.width = '75';
      td.contentEditable = true;
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("text"));
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
  myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
addTable();
```

```html
<div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to operate on tables, [use corrects javascript instructions ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement)

```js
const 
  DynTb = document.getElementById('myDynamicTable')
  rn    = +window.prompt("Input number of rows", 1) 
, cn    = +window.prompt("Input number of columns", 1)
  ;
if( isNaN(rn) || isNaN(cn))
  throw 'bad integer input value (s)'

const myTable = addTable(DynTb, rn, cn )

function addTable(tDiv, rn, cn) 
  {
  let 
    tab = tDiv.appendChild( document.createElement('table') )
  , tBy = tab.createTBody()
    ;
  for(let r=0;r<rn;++r)
    {
    let row = tBy.insertRow() 
    for(let c=0;c<cn;++c) 
      {
      row.insertCell().innerHTML = 
          `<input type="text" placeHolder="${r}-${c}">`
    } }
  return tab
  }
```

```css
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td {
  padding    : .2em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
input {
  width : 5em;
  }
```

```html
<div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
```